# postgres> Create a trigger in another schema

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgres 9.5 and I loin to a database xyz as postgres user.
Now I need to create a trigger in schema abc. The trigger will be a before delete or update on table Tab1 which is in schema def.

```
psql -d xyz

xyz=#create trigger abc.trg_name before delete or update on col1 ON DEF.Tab1
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE abc.proc1();
```

However, I am unable to do so. I get syntax error near "."

when I try using doublequotes, the TRIGGER gets created but not in abc schema - in DEF schema ( the schema of the underlying table):

```sql
create trigger "abc.trg_name" before delete or update on col1 ON DEF.Tab1
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE abc.proc1();
```

Is there a way in Postgres to create trigger in a schema different from its underlying referenced table?

I tried setting the SEARCH_PATH to abc, but it still creates it under DEF schema.
Thanks for reply in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No.

The [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createtrigger.html) says

> The name cannot be schema-qualified — the trigger inherits the schema
>   of its table.